# Usage of volatile keyword

Tags: c#, volatile

I am reading about volatile keyword and wondering how would the below scenario workout.

```
Class SomeClass
 {
  volatile int i = 10;
 }
```

Two threads are trying to modify the variable i.

```
Thread 1 does i = i + 1;
Thread 2 does i = i - 1;
```

The sequence of operations is as follows:

Thread 1 reads variable i to CPU register.
Thread switch happens at this point.
Thread 2 reads variable i and decrements it by 1 so now value of i is 9;
Thread 1 is scheduled again, now will the thread 1 take the i value form register (which is 10) and increment it to 11 and write it back to i or will it read from the original source and read the i value as 9 and increment it to 10?

Thanks

Comment: While you're at reading about `volatile`, I recommend you to read [Eric Lippert's explanation about it](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/06/16/atomicity-volatility-and-immutability-are-different-part-three.aspx). Short conclusion: don't use it.

Answer (score 8):

The increment/decrement operations are not atomic, so the race condition that you have described is entirely possible.  The use of `volatile` doesn't prevent it.  You would need to use a `lock`, or possibly `Interlocked.Increment`, instead, to ensure that the operations are each atomic.

Comment: I thought the same thing, but when after I read this blog post http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/05/31/atomicity-volatility-and-immutability-are-different-part-three.aspx from Eric Lippert I am confused

Comment: @SriHarshaVelicheti What are you confused about?

Comment: @SriHarshaVelicheti: That blog post mentions "every volatile field read and write is also atomic", and in fact, this is a property of the data types themselves (int, char, etc). Note that it does _not_ mean that any composite operation like a `(read, increment by 1, write)` will be atomic. All it means is that a read/write won't get cut off halfway, but because the examples you gave were composite operations, they are still not thread safe.

Comment: This is the part from the blog that confused me "In C#, "volatile" means not only "make sure that the compiler and the jitter do not perform any code reordering or register caching optimizations on this variable". It also means "tell the processors to do whatever it is they need to do to ensure that I am reading the latest value, even if that means halting other processors and making them synchronize main memory with their caches"." So when the Thread 1 gets scheduled for first time and tries to read variable i doesn't it get it from original source instead of CPU registers?

Comment: @SriHarshaVelicheti Yes, it does, *but that doesn't remove the race condition*.  All it means is that when you state, "Thread 1 reads variable i to CPU register." that that read is reading the latest value *at that point in time*.  It doesn't prevent another thread from also reading the value and mutating it before that thread can make its changes and save them back.  `volatile` simply doesn't provide that guarantee; `lock` does.

Answer (score 0):

As you wrote "Thread 1 is scheduled again, now will the thread 1 take the i value form register (which is 10) and increment it to 11 and write it back to i or will it read from the original source and read the i value as 9 and increment it to 10?" - EDIT: with help of @Servy: the 1-st thread will use value of 10 because it was previously read to perform next add operation.

Comment: No, actually, it won't.  It performed the volatile read and ensured that when it went to grab the updated value from memory that that read wouldn't be reordered with respect to certain writes.  That read won't be re-executed just because the value is written after the read and before some manipulation of the read value takes place.  The given program is simply *not* free of race conditions.  It needs a `lock` to ensure that the read/add/write is treated as being atomic.

Comment: @Servy ok, but it results to the most actual value to be read, no?

Comment: At the time the read logically takes place, which is before the write from the other thread, so there is no update.  You can't just mark your field `volatile` and then perform a whole bunch of non-atomic operations and have them be synchronized.  Only `lock` would do that for you.  `volatile` is only useful if all of the operations you want to perform are *already* atomic.  This operation is *not*.

Comment: @Servy Right, but i'm not talking about syncronising a bunch of operations. I'm talking about "now will the thread 1 take the i value form register" and "r will it read from the original source and read the i value as 9 ". So it's about the single read operation, not the whole programm. I suppose this single read operation will be atomic and will get the most actual value, or even this statements is false?

Comment: It *did* do an actual read.  When it did that read the first time it ensures that it gets the real value, not a cached value, and that the value isn't cached in another CPU's cache.  After that read completes, and it stores the result in its register, it's not going to go *back* to memory and *read it again* just because it was updated by another thread.  The code has one read, one read is performed.  If another thread modifies the variable after it has been read, but before it writes the value back, then that's fine.  `volatile` doesn't prevent that, you're (falsely) claiming that it does.

Comment: That's it! Thanks @Servy for "It did do an actual read". I've missed that :)